# reducerComponent can't be found in ReasonReact

Tags: reason, reason-react

I'm trying to follow this [Reason React tutorial](https://jaredforsyth.com/2017/07/05/a-reason-react-tutorial/) to build a simple TodoApp:

However when changing the type of the component from `statelessComponent` to `reducerComponent` I get the following error:

```
We've found a bug for you!
/Users/harald/projects/reason/a-reason-react-tutorial/src/TodoApp.re 8:17-44

 6 │ type state = {items: list item}; 
 7 │
 8 │ let component = ReasonReact.reducerComponent "TodoApp";
 9 │
10 │ let se = ReasonReact.stringToElement;


The value reducerComponent can't be found in ReasonReact
```

Comment: This sounds like you have an outdated copy of reason-react. Can you check which version you are on?

Comment: Thanks! I had version 0.2.1 from the sample project. After upgrading to 0.2.4 it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found n the comments to be an outdated copy of reason-react. `reducerComponent` was introduced in reason-react 0.2.4. `npm update reason-react` should fix it.